# How to save create a folder and save an image in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-file

I am trying to capture some images and save them in offline storage. I am not storing the images in app directory but instead in ...

```
String myNewBarcodeFolder = '/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/images';
```

and doing...

```
await Directory(myNewBarcodeFolder).create(recursive: true);
```

this is the error I am receiving

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Prepacking' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

And yes I've asked for the permissions in my manifest as well as in my permissions_manager.dart file

```
void requestAllPermission() async {
  var cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
  if (!cameraStatus.isGranted) {
    await Permission.camera.request();
  }
  var writeStorageStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
  if (!writeStorageStatus.isGranted) {
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  }
  var readStorageStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (!readStorageStatus.isGranted) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
}
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Wrong path. Use an existing public directory on external storage to create your folders and files in. For manage external storage obtained your app should be able to write anywhere.

Comment: You cannot go for manage external storage at runtime if you did not mention that in manifest file.

Comment: @blackapps hello sir can you Please provide me a minimal code to write files in Internal storage of device. also the above code is working on emulator with Android 9 but not on a real device with Android 11.

Comment: Your code looks ok. You only should change used path as suggested. Strange you are not reacting on the manage external storage.

Comment: @blackapps was right, in android 10 and above we also need to add ManageExternalStorage permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Adding only ReadExternalStorage and WriteExternalStorage is not enough for Android9< devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code on my mobile device (Samsung A70) and work fine, which created the folders *MyApp/images*.

```
String path = '/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/images';

//Request permission
await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

var stickDirectory = Directory(path);
await stickDirectory.create(recursive: true);
```

Comment: Thank you @a-rokbi . It's the right solution, also to everyone else: add the permissions in Android Manifest too.